# Why is "return -1;" not part of a conditional statement in Khan Academy's Binary Search Algorithm Challenge?

Tags: algorithm, khan-academy

I'm working through the [Khan Academy Binary Search Algorithm Challenge](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/binary-search/p/challenge-binary-search) and I've searched through the questions related to that challenge on this site, but haven't found a question like mine related to it.

My question is why the `return -1;` expression isn't part of a conditional statement such that the result `-1` is returned only in case the prime number being searched for isn't in the array?

I've managed to solve the challenge on my own but that's because this part of the function is already given by the challenge. So I don't understand why in the function below, `return -1;` comes at the end after the `while` loop and seems to apply in any condition. This would seem to me to yield a result of `-1` whether or not the `targetValue` is in the array (even though that's not in fact the case and the function works as it should).

```
/* Returns either the index of the location in the array,
  or -1 if the array did not contain the targetValue */
var doSearch = function(array, targetValue) {
    var min = 0;
    var max = array.length - 1;
    var guess;
    while(min <= max) {
        guess = Math.floor((max + min)/2);
        if(array[guess]===targetValue) {
            return guess;
        }
        else if(array[guess] < targetValue) {
            min = guess + 1;
        }
        else {
            max = guess - 1;
        }
        println(guess);
    }
    return -1;
};
var primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 
        41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97];

var result = doSearch(primes, 73);
println("Found prime at index " + result);
```

Comment: Because of the `return guess;` inside the loop; once that's reached, nothing else in the function is executed.

Comment: First of all, are you familiar with binary search? If not, read up on binary search first (the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) is a good start). This is a traditional implementation of binary search. Either `targetValue` is in `array`, or it isn't. If it is, the line with `return guess` inside the loop will be reached, so the function stops there. If it's not, the loop terminates and `return -1` is reached.

Comment: @jonrsharpe @Filipe Thanks, I get that. But then why does `return guess` come only after the first conditional expression in the while loop? Shouldn't it also appear at the end of the `else if` and/or `else` expressions if either of those conditions hold and not the first `if` condition?

Comment: Have you considered stepping through the example, e.g. on paper or in a debugger? Why would you expect an early return in cases where you *haven't* yet found the target?!

Comment: Wow, I now see exactly what you mean @jonrsharpe! 
Okay so then as long as the `return` command is executed _where appropriate_ in the loop, then the `return` command that follows the loop will be passed over. I guess I didn't understand that but will be sure to remember it now. Thanks for the assistance. 
p.s. I'm obviously an early beginner so thanks for bearing with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number is found, the return statement inside the while loop will pass the control of the program to the calling function. In other words, it will come out of the function.

If min > max, it implies that the given number couldn't be found and it will come out of the while loop and return -1.